# How to post a login in tcl using http

Tags: rest, http, post, tcl

I am being asked to update a tool written in tcl/tk ? itcl.

I can do the work in Bash or Python, but have not figured out how to do in tcl without the CURL library.

Bash script login to REST API

```
curl --silent --fail -c cjar -k -X POST 
     -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"data": [ "root", "passwrd" ] }' 
     https://testsystem.abc.com/login)
```

That will be followed by a query

```
curl --silent --fail -c cjar -b cjar -k 
     -H 'Content-Type: application/json' 
     -X GET https://testsystem.abc.com/org/embeddedsystem/control/power0/attr/state
```

test.itcl

```
#Test Connection?
set token [http::geturl https://testsystem.abc.com/]
set postStat [http::status $token]
puts "$postStat"
set responseBody [http::data $token]
puts "$responseBody"
# this outputs OK, and need to login.
set token [http::geturl https://testsystem.abc.com/login -query -headers $hdr  ]'
```

HTTP how do you do sending data like in the first curl Command.

Answer (score 2):

Cookie Jars are not (yet) implemented in Tcl, but because you do not need to deal with stuff like path, public prefixes, expiration and so on, this is easy.

First make the login request:

```
set logintoken [http::geturl https://testsystem.abc.com/login -header [list {Content-Type: application/json}] -query {{"data": [ "root", "passwrd" ] }}]
```

Next you need to parse the returned `Set-Cookie` headers:

```
set cookielist {}
foreach {key value} [http::meta $logintoken] {
    if {$key eq "Set-Cookie"} {
        lappend cookies [lindex [split $value ";"] 0]
    }
}
set cookies "Cookie: [join $cookielist "; "]"
# Good style, free the memory for the last http request
http::cleanup $logintoken
```

After that, just issue the authenticated request with the cookie:

```
set token [http::geturl https://testsystem.abc.com/org/embeddedsystem/control/power0/attr/state -headers [list {Content-Type: application/json} $cookies]]
```

Comment: That's pretty much all that cookies do. Oh, there's also some stuff with persistence and security, but they're not too important for talking to an API.

Comment: Yeah, no need to deal with public prefixes, matching the host, expiration time of cookies, public prefixes (like .co.uk), https only cookies and so on.

Comment: The Login in line now has
BGERROR: missing value to go with key
errorInfo: missing value to go with key
    while executing
"http::geturl https://wsbmc009/login -headers [list {Content-Type: application/json}] -query {{"data": [ "root", "passw0rd" ] }}"
    (object "::openbmcconnect0" method "::openbmcconnect::connect"

Answer (score 0):

the Login I figured out.
and the cookies works with a few code fixes from above.